# Adding Pharmacology Dictionary to Gedit

Tags: gedit, dictionary, spell-checking

I write a lot of things that talk about medications and, as you can imagine, it is not the easiest thing in the world to spell.

Unless my Google-Fu has failed me tremendously, I have not been able to find a way to add a dictionary of drug names to the Gedit dictionary.

I know I can do this in Open/LibreOffice, however I do not want to use them and prefer Gedit for all of the things I write as it is just better for my needs.

Are there any thoughts on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Do you already have such a dictionary, and if so what format is it in? or do you wish to create a dictionary from scratch?

Comment: @steeldriver I have a word list available to me with about ~700,000 entries. I have it in a txt format for easiest transition to anything else that may need to happen to it.

Comment: Well as far as I can tell, the gedit spellchecker plugin uses `enchant` under the hood. Although `enchant` is configured to use multiple underlying spelling engines (`aspell`, `ispell` etc.), the first places it looks AFAIK are `~/.config/enchant/` and `/usr/share/enchant/`. (If you've added words to a custom dictionary in gedit, they probably got saved in a `~/.config/enchant/en_US.dic` or similar file.) So I'd probably start there. The format seems to be plain text, one word per line.

Comment: @steeldriver If you want to go ahead and make that an answer, it is a perfect setup and I will totally give you the credit for it.